# Count users where subscription end within month Linq c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I just want to count users where their subscription end date is within the coming month:

```
int Count = oUsers
            .Where(x =>
            0 < x.SubscriptionEnddate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days < 30)
            .Count();
```

But its not working.

What I want to do  is **0 < Value < 30**.

Comment: Why rule out `&&` - it's by far the most readable solution?

Comment: Sounds like x y problem. What do you really want to achieve? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: I'd restructure it entirely, to work out the bounds beforehand as local variables, then use `int count = oUsers.Count(x => x.SubscriptionEnddate >= lowerBound && x.SubscriptionEnddate < upperBound);`

Comment: Why don't you write out your query in text instead, and then rewrite it without all the math (I guess you're trying to prevent to subtract twice)? What's with the date subtraction? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd also urge you to think about time zones. What time zone is your data stored in? Is it the same as the machine where you're using `DateTime.Now`? Are you sure you don't want `DateTime.UtcNow` or similar?

Comment: Something like `math.abs(x-(a+b)/2) <= (b-a)/2` might work

Comment: without && operator: `!(Value <= 0 || 30 <= Value)` solved as requested

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I'm not quite sure, but to me it looks like XY has already turned into Yak shaving this time.

Comment: Just want to check value between two, I think && is not compulsory for this purpose?

Comment: Do you really want to check whether `SubscriptionEnddate` is between 30 and 60 days ahead of the current date? I doubt so, but thats what you do in your code. Is your current code correctly working and you really just want to shorten it? If it's not, please make sure to get a valid query before trying to optimize it in any way.

Comment: @grek40 It just means the subscription ends the coming month. I can see cases where that might be relevant

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes, You right

Comment: If PatrickHofman is right... how 'right' is he exactly? Do you actually want to get a month based information or do you really want to talk about day counts?

Comment: I just want to count user where Subscription end within next 30 days

Comment: But you don't... you count users where Subscription end within 30-60 days ahead. Thats why I asked if your current query is returning the correct result or not.

Comment: @grek40 Sorry its my logical mistake, Edit has been made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&&`. Period. It is where it is designed for.

You can circumvent this by creating a `Between` extension method, or concatenate two `Where` clauses, but really, why trade that over `&&`. But if you insist:

```
int c = oUsers
        .Select(x=> x.SubscriptionEnddate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)).Days)
        .Where(d => 0 < d)
        .Where(d => d < 30)
        .Count();
```

Comment: @Govind: Need more help? Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
int count = oUsers.Where(x=> x.Days > 0).Count(x => x.Days < 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way to keep it readable:

```
int Count =
    oUsers
        .Select(u => new
        {
            u,
            days = u.SubscriptionEnddate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)).Days,
        })
        .Where(x => x.days > 0 && x.days < 30)
        .Select(x => x.u)
        .Count();
```

This obviously uses `&&` but it eliminates the code duplication which I think is what you're really trying to avoid.

The use of `.Count()` at the end removes the need to keep track of the original value, so, as Patrick has already posted, this suffices:

```
int Count =
    oUsers
        .Select(u => u.SubscriptionEnddate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)).Days)
        .Where(x => x > 0 && x < 30)
        .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not always the shorter why is better.

When someone else will read your code it will be much easier for him to understand when you calling SomeRange method

I think the best why is when the code more readable so you can do method for returning if your value is match the start and end ranges and call it.

example for some int range but the same why you can check dates

```
    public static bool SomeRange(int value,int start,int end)
    {
        return (value > start && value < end);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> valueList = new List<int> { 1,65,3,76,34,23,11,5,665,334};
        var result = valueList.Where(x => SomeRange(x, 0, 30)).Count();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Solve it with Enumerable.Range:

`oUsers.Where(x => x.SubscriptionEnddate != null && Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Contains(x.SubscriptionEnddate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days)).Count()`;

Comment: Just so you know, this is like 30 times more inefficient than comparing for start && end of the desired range.

Comment: So you suggesting && operator?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, precompute the range start and end before executing the count, then compare for `start && end`:

```
// some test data
var oUsers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => new { SubscriptionEnddate = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now.AddDays(x) });

var rangeStart = DateTime.Now;
var rangeEnd = rangeStart.AddDays(30);
// Conditional count... can also be done as .Where(condition).Count()
int Count = oUsers.Count(x => x.SubscriptionEnddate >= rangeStart && x.SubscriptionEnddate < rangeEnd);
```

Possibly use `DateTime.Today` instead since you are only interested in days.

Answer (score -1):

You could use nested if statements, if you're really opposed to using `&&`

```
if x.SubscriptionEnddate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)).Days > 0 {
  if x.SubscriptionEnddate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)).Days < 30 {
    int count = oUsers;
  }

}
```

This seems like an incredibly obtuse way to go about this though. This is why we have the `&&` operator.

Comment: Or you could just downvote me because it's not what you want to hear? Truth hurts I guess.

Comment: `if` statements won't work within the `Where` part of a linq query.

Comment: It does, but you have to wrap them in a code block @JamesThorpe

Comment: @PatrickHofman True.  Even worse than just using `&&` though :)