# c# Count rows in DataTable where all values of row equal to 1

Tags: c#

I have a datatable in which the columns and rows are created at runtime, so as a result the column names may vary and row numbers too. Values for each cell can only be 1 or 0.

I may get a datatable with say for example 3 columns. e.g.

```
Age | Sex | Location
-------------------
1   | 0   | 1
-------------------
0   | 1   | 0
--------------------
1   | 1   | 1
--------------------
0   | 1   | 0
--------------------
1   | 1   | 1
--------------------
```

I want to be able to count only the rows which contain 1 on each column. So above example would return 2.

Comment: Any effort from your side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514985/count-users-where-subscription-end-within-month-linq-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count users where subscription end within month Linq c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514985/count-users-where-subscription-end-within-month-linq-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the rows and columns:

```
int rows = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    if (!dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => row[x.ColumnName]?.ToString() != "1"))
        rows++;
```

Comment: @nerdalert: Did you try this? Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved.